# Synonym for a heavily modified or self-made car or thing

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word for the following things (they may be the same, or have different words):

- cheap car modified or constructed by owner using scrapyard and low-end tools (and thus having certain "quality")
- cheap car with expensive and redundant modifications (golden bumpers?)
- a regular car which has almost all parts removed and/or replaced to make it more lightweight and faster up to make it unusable for everyday use
- not a car but technically complex thing fits any description above

The only words I've found are junker and jalopy, but may be there is more?

EDIT: Commenters asked me to present a sample sentence, but unfortunately I'm trying to find a name for a blog, so there is no sample sentence. May be "%word% Lab" or something.

Comment: 2) The car has been "pimped". 3) The car has been stripped down.

Comment: Can you create a sentence where you would use this word?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to find a name for a blog, so there is no sample sentence. May be "%word% Lab" or something

Answer (score 2):

I suggest **customized** (BrE customised). [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/customize) has

> **customize**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> Made or done to order; custom-made.
>
> *Modifying or customizing a vehicle has also become a trend among car enthusiasts nowadays.*
>
> *Every bike is unique because everyone customises their bike to reflect their individual personalities.*

---

Similar to this is the term **custom car**. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Custom_car) has

> A **custom car** is a passenger vehicle that has been either substantially altered to improve its performance, often by altering or replacing the engine and transmission; made into a personal "styling" statement, using paint work and aftermarket accessories to make the car look unlike any car as delivered from the factory; or some combination of both.
> <sub>*Batmobile*</sub>
> [image]

And then there is the **kustom car** in a particular style, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kustom_(cars)).

> **Kustoms** are modified cars from the 1930s to the early 1960s, done in the customizing styles of that time period.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be hard-pressed to find a word that perfectly fits all four of your descriptions. That said, one that comes to mind for me and which may get you close is *jerry-build*, which can be used as a noun or a verb meaning:

> jerry-build: *to build cheaply and flimsily* ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jerry-build))

For the record, though, I'm also a huge fan of @Weather Vane's more specific suggestions for your examples two and three: *pimped* and *stripped down*, respectively.

Comment: Well, a word for one description would be suitable too. In my language there is a separate word (and even multiple words) for every description, although some of them are not widely used